# Incorrect Pygame touch events from Raspi Display without startx

Tags: touchscreen, startx, pygame

I have a Clock / Weather / MPD client PyGame application that runs on a Raspi3 with an official Raspi Touchscreen.  The app works fine when executed under startx.   When started from the command line, the app works perfect except touch responses are way off.  USB mouse responses work fine.

I’ve downgraded SDL libraries to 1.2, executed the app as both root and pi and tried 
os.putenv ("SDL_MOUSEDEV" , "/dev/input/event2"), as suggested by others, with no effect on touch response validity.

Is there a trick to getting valid touch responses with a Raspi Touchscreen and Pygame without using a window manager?